# Template parse errors: 'router-outlet' is not a known element

Tags: angular

I can not find out why this is happening. From what I can see I am importing everything correctly. I have gone to other questions and have looked this over many times. I am probably missing something very simple and just not seeing it. Can I get some help as to why I am getting this error?

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../dashboard/dashboard.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts: I did not create this from the start of the project and that is why I am probably missing something.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from '../dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

In the app.component.html I have placed the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: that worked. can you please create an answer so i can accept it

Comment: So my answer is not correct?

Comment: sorry selected to wrong one by accident. I fixed it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should tell angular that you're going to use directives from `RouterModule`. 
That said, you should either import `RouterModule` in `AppModule` or export `RouterModule` from `AppRoutingModule`. The second option is preferable because you keep all related to the routing stuff in one place.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]   <==== add this
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to exports router module, so your `app.module.ts` can access to imported modules from `app.routing.ts` module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

In the official [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#refactor-the-routing-configuration-into-a-routing-module) it is said:

> Finally, **re-export** the Angular RouterModule by adding it to the module
>   exports array. By ***re-exporting*** the RouterModule here and importing
>   AppRoutingModule in AppModule, the components declared in AppModule
>   will have access to router directives such as RouterLink and
>   RouterOutlet.